# How to insert tabs on new line in Vim before a character is typed

Tags: vim, indentation

If I write an if statement in my C program, press enter three times, then write a comment, the below is my output. Notice the two lines between the condition and the comment are completely empty.

```
if(my_condition) {


<Tab>// My comment here
```

My issue is that Vim does not insert any tab character(s) between the beginning of the line and the cursor position *until a character is typed*. This is very annoying for me, because I like to move my cursor up and down the block of code often. Since there isn't a real tab on the two lines, if I moved up one line my cursor would go to the beginning of the line, instead of staying on the same column. I come from Sublime Text and other editors where this has never been a problem.

Is there a plugin or setting such that I can accomplish the following?

```
if(my_condition) {
<Tab>
<Tab>
<Tab>// My comment here
```

All help is appreciated. I've looked into using Visual mode, but have had undesirable side effects of enabling it all the time. Certainly there is a simple way to automatically add the tabs when I make a new line?

Comment: Can you try `:set autoindent`

Comment: No. You don't want lines with only whitespace. Nobody wants that.

Comment: At best you can enable the virtualcolunm feature.

Comment: "Since there isn't a real tab on the two lines, if I moved up one line my cursor would go to the beginning of the line, instead of staying on the same column." Why is that a problem?

Comment: @romainl, may be because the use of `i_CTRL-F` must be explicit in order to insert text in the right column?

Comment: or use `S` or `cc` to enter insert mode at the right indent level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is very annoying for me, because I like to move my cursor up and down the block of code often.

Well, as you might have noticed, switching to vim means that you need to change your own editing behavior. And that might be the toughest, more than learning the new commands, because habits die hard!

I'm not saying that you should stop scrolling around your function in an useless manner, though, but that you should stop moving around with the "cursor" keys in insert mode.

When you're doing movements when in insert mode it has the side effect you're exposing as "inconvenient", but it also has the side effect of breaking the "repeat" command (`.`). After a cursor movement in insert mode, a `.` will only repeat characters typed after that movement.

So, what you should consider in your editing behavior, is to avoid empty lines, avoid trailing spaces/tabs and never move around in insert mode. Insert mode is for insertion, and the normal mode is for moving around and doing actions on the text.

There are a lot of move commands you can abuse in normal mode (`j`/`k`, `<C-e>`/`<C-y>`, `{`/`}`, …).

That being said, if you get yourself in a situation where you've fscked the indentation, you might want to keep on editing, not caring about the indent, and once you're back in normal mode issue a `=i{` that will indent everything within the block following the syntax file (and your indent settings).

Comment: I guess I'm just holding on to how I've always used my editors, and Insert mode's enabled me to do that. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: I believe that's the toughest thing when switching to an editor so radically different in the experience like vim is. But believe me (and Romain, and Luc), it's so much worth it. Once you've learned how to live in normal mode and do all your editing actions in normal mode only, you feel like you've taken the red pill in Matrix ☺